Chrome Bookmark keeps cache after hard refresh
Problem
We published a new version of our application. If users go to the application by clicking on a Chrome bookmark, they get the older version. Going to the same URL in any different manner will yield the most recent version. This is despite doing a Hard Refresh. The problem seems similar to the one described in this question which corresponds to an older Chrome version and an Angular application.
Setup
React app server by an NGINX web server which has cache-control: max-age=0 . Chrome version 127.0.6522.122.
Question
Why is the caching behavior for bookmarks different from the regular caching mechanism? What are recommendations on how to clean this cache without deleting the bookmark and creating a new one?
